# How to solve these series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-sum

Can anyone help me understand how to solve these two series?  More than the solution I'm interested in understanding which process I should follow.

- Series 1:

$$
 \sum_{i = 3}^{\infty} i * a^{i-1}, 0 < a < 1.
$$

- Series 2:

$$
 \sum_{i = 3}^{\infty} i\sum_{k = 2}^{i-1} a^{i-k} * b^{k-2} , 0 < a < 1, 0 < b < 1.
$$

These two series come as part of a long mathematical proof which I omitted for brevity, if you think it is relevant I will post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: For the first one if $\sum_{i = 3}^{\infty} x^{i}=f(x)$ then $\sum_{i = 3}^{\infty} i \times x^{i-1}=f'(x)$.

---

For the second one consider that:
$$
\sum_{k = 2}^{i-1} a^{i-k}  b^{k-2}=a^{i-2}\frac{1-\frac{b^{i-2}}{a^{i-2}}}{1-\frac{b}{a}}= \frac{a^{i-2}-{b^{i-2}}}{1-\frac{b}{a}} 
$$
Then you can decompose the series into two one and use the previous step.

Comment: Is your hint valid also considering a as a known value?

Comment: You can start by assuming a variable $x$ and then you can replace $x$ with a known $a$. In any case $f'(x)$ means differentiating a function with respect to a variable $x$. This gives a solution for all $|a|<1$.

Comment: Something that should be added is the radius of convergence for your series. The series is not convergent for all $a<1$ (for instance $a=-3$). You have to consider $|a|<1$.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to write that in the question, a is positive and less than 1

Comment: so the second sum of the second series is a particular application of the geometric series? and how did you get that result?

Comment: Yes, the second some is a finite geometric series. Look at here for more details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_geometric_series#Geometric_series

Comment: I'm still trying to solve $\sum_{k = 2}^{i-1} a^{i-k}  b^{k-2}$, can you give me a little suggestion on the next step? I tried $\sum_{k = 2}^{i-1} a^{i-k}  b^{k-2} = \sum_{k = 2}^{i-1} a^{i-k}  \sum_{k = 2}^{i-1}b^{k-2}$ and then doing a variable change but couldn't get your same result

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10927/discussion-between-arash-and-matteo)

Answer (score 2):

For the first one, recall that $$\frac{1}{1 - x} = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{\infty} x^n = 1 + x + x^2 + ...$$

Differentiating both sides leads to

$$\frac{1}{(1 - x)^2} = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} = 1 + 2x + 3x^2 + ... = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} nx^{n - 1}$$

This is valid within the disk of convergence, which has radius $1$ around $x = 0$.